# Order by multipe columns together and limit the records in DDB

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am trying to model the below table using DynamoDB:

`A (String) | B (String) | C (String) | D (Integer) | E (Integer) | start_date (Timestamp) | end_date (Timestamp) where <A, B, C> columns uniquely define each tuple`

The query pattern is: **Give list of top 10 distinct C's with A equal to 'Y' ordered by D and E together where current time stamp is between start_date and end_date**

For the above query pattern, one way to model the above table in dynamodb would be to have (A) as partition key and (D#E#B#C) as range key so that I would have records sorted by D and E on which I could apply the limits. We could model this in DDB as shown below:

`A (partition key) | D#E#B#C (Sort key) | D | E | start_date | end_date`

One more way to model this would be to combine D and E together to form a LSI in which case, the table would look like:

`A (partition key) | B#C (Sort key) | D#E (LSI) | start_date | end_date`

But the above design looks non-optimal because the sort key (B#C) doesn't actually serve any purpose other than just making tuple unique by combining with partition key (A). Having records sorted by (B#C) does not help much in my use-case.

In both the designs, modeling order by columns (D and E) looks bit ugly to me given the fact that I will have to convert Integers to Strings and concatenate them just because I have to include them under sort key or LSI. Also, limiting records based on "order by" clause is very important to me as I can't afford to return many records without limits during the network call from DB.

With relational database and SQL, the query would be **SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 C from table where A = 'value' and current_timestamp between start_date and end_date order by desc D, E** with multi-column index on (start_date, end_date, D, E) and primary key (A, B, C). Multi-column index here is not a deal breaker for me because we have strict SLAs only for reads but not writes/updates/deletes.

Is there any better NoSQL modeling choice for the above table which could help in optimising the above query pattern? Would RDS be a better choice for modeling the above table?

Comment: Why are you considering DynamoDB? This query is easy to express in RDS. If your scale is low enough, just use RDS. If your scale is such that RDS can't handle it, then the fact it's easy to express in RDS won't be much help, and you'll need to find a design that scales better, which is basically what DynamoDB is pushing you toward by eliminating your ability to express such a compute-intensive hard-to-scale query.

Comment: @hunterhacker, Only issue is due to order by and limit clauses I feel. I can't do those filtering in application code because otherwise ddb would probably return 6000-7000 records in every network call as I mentioned above and we would probably lose the latency advantage that DDB provides due to this. Do you see any way to model this better?

Comment: What about the distinct top 10. That’s another challenge, no?

Comment: Yeah, true. But distinct top 10 makes sense only if I use order by. If I do sorting in application code, even distinct and top 10 logic would be part of application code. But unfortunately I can't do that.

Comment: Sounds like you're forcing yourself to use DDB when what you really need is a relational database - perhaps see if PartiQL can carry out the above query but if not, you sound like you have relational data or perhaps DDB is not the right NoSQL DB choice.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I am not forcing myself. I am just trying to evaluate SQL and NoSQL options for my use-case. I posted the question with DDB tag here to check if I am missing something as far as NoSQL modeling is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your patterns are not well suited to DynamoDB. Distinct top 10 can be difficult to achieve in DynamoDB.

If you still want to go with a serverless approach you can try Amazon Aurora which is serverless and includes a [Dataplane API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html) which can simplify connections.

Amazon Aurora is a fully managed relational database engine that's compatible with MySQL and PostgreSQL.